# In the tensorflow set to cuda Using a keras in tensorflow with cpu in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, keras, cpu

I am run ML all the gpu in the cuda environment.

And for other tasks, I need to operate tensorflow using cpu.

When I run it without any settings, it runs as the GPU by default and causes the following error.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.

This error probably occurred using all GPUs.

Is there a command that can run keras in tensorflow  with the CPU?